# How to implement logic gates using assembly code?

Tags: assembly, logic, microcontroller, 8051

I'm preparing for a digital systems exam and I have a past paper question as below: implement AND and NAND gate using assembly code. There's no mark scheme for the paper so I can't look up how to do it. If anyone can explain this it would be appreciated.

[image]

I've researched the four commands it says to use and I understand that ANL performs an AND operation, and CPL performs a NOT operation. However I'm not sure how to implement these using the other commands, and as the question is worth 10 marks, 5 for each gate, I don't think just writing the single commands like this will be enough:

a) `ANL P1^0, P1^1`

b)`ANL P1^0, P1^1`

`CPL P1^0`

My idea was that maybe the MOV command should be used to store the value of the port pin in a variable for use in the command, and then used again to output to P1^2 at the output of the gate, but I'm not 100% sure about this and it also doesn't explain where the SJMP command comes in.

Comment: `ANL` does not take two memory operands, and you'd need an output too. Hint: use the `C` flag.

Comment: PS: You don't have to use everything you are allowed to :)

Comment: @Jester From what I can tell, it performs AND on the two operands and stores the result in the first operand. This is why I then used CPL on the first operand in part b), in order to invert the output of the AND gate, forming a NAND gate. Would this be incorrect? And if so are you able to explain why? Thanks!

Comment: Let's take `ANL P1^0, P1^1`. If it were legal, which it isn't, it would update `P1^0` as you said and that is not what the circuit is doing. You must not change any of the inputs. More hint: load one input into `C`, perform the `AND` then write it out to the appropriate place.

Comment: @Jester that makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, I've now found the complete solution. C is used to hold temporary values, and the pins can be used in the commands.

For an AND gate:

```
loop: MOV C, P1^0     ; Assign value on pin 1.0 to C
      ANL C, P1^1     ; Perform AND and store result in C
      MOV P1^2, C     ; Assign new value of C to output pin
      SJMP loop       ; Jump to top of statement and run again
```

For OR gate, use ORL instead of ANL.
For NOR or NAND, use CPL command to invert C before copying to output pin.

Answer (score -1):

AND gate and NAND gate are similar together because they have concidencing characteristics not only for calculations but for the other benefits for invent C to copy paste.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).